# How to reconstruct a .ui file from pyuic .py file

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, pyuic

A while back I made a project using PyQt. I created some .ui files and generated the corresponding .py files using  pyuic4. I want to start work on it again, but I have lost the .ui files (I formatted my PC and took a backup, but the .ui files were residing in the Qt designer folder and got lost).

Is there any way I can restore those .ui files from the .py files generated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting .py to .ui file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822786/converting-py-to-ui-file)

Comment: @Yoann. The accepted answer for that question is wrong, and does not give helpful advice.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to do this using [QFormBuilder](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qformbuilder.html):

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtDesigner
from myui import Ui_Dialog

def dump_ui(widget, path):
    builder = QtDesigner.QFormBuilder()
    stream = QtCore.QFile(path)
    stream.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
    builder.save(stream, widget)
    stream.close()

app = QtGui.QApplication([''])

dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
Ui_Dialog().setupUi(dialog)

dialog.show()
    
dump_ui(dialog, 'myui.ui')
```

(NB: showing the window seems to be quite important in order to get the best results).

Don't expect to get a perfect reconstruction of your original ui file, though. You will almost certainly need to do quite a lot of tidying up to get something acceptable - but if your ui is quite complex, it should still be worth it.