# How to restore resource.qrc file from resources_rc.py

Tags: python, pyqt, resources, restore, pyrcc

As I am facing data loss, I have a corrupted `resource.qrc` file when I tried recovering it and I also lost my graphics files (.png, .jpg) - but my Qt application is running fine.

The problem is when I need to edit the `.ui` files, I have a corrupted `resource.qrc` file. My `resources_rc.py` file is all well, which I created by the following command:

```
pyrcc4 -o resource.py resource.qrc
```

So is there any way I can get my `resource.qrc` back from the `resources_rc.py` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script below will reconstruct a qrc file and all the original resources from a `resources_rc.py` file generated by `pyrcc`. It will work with PyQt4/5 and Python 2/3. The files will be written to a temporary directory in the same directory as the given `resources_rc.py` file.

Usage:

```
python qrc_gen.py path/to/resources_rc.py
```

*qrc_gen.py*:

```
import sys, os, tempfile
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
from PyQt4 import QtCore
# from PyQt5 import QtCore

respath = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
dirpath = os.path.dirname(respath)
sys.path.insert(0, dirpath)

import resources_rc

tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix='qrc_', dir=dirpath)

it = QtCore.QDirIterator(':', QtCore.QDirIterator.Subdirectories)

files = []

while it.hasNext():
    uri = it.next()
    path = uri.lstrip(':/')
    if path.startswith('qt-project.org'):
        continue
    tmp = os.path.join(tmpdir, path)
    if it.fileInfo().isDir():
        try:
            os.makedirs(tmp)
        except OSError:
            pass
    else:
        res = QtCore.QFile(uri)
        res.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
        with open(tmp, 'wb') as stream:
            stream.write(bytes(res.readAll()))
        res.close()
        files.append('    <file>%s</file>\n' % path.lstrip(':/'))

with open(os.path.join(tmpdir, 'resources.qrc'), 'w') as stream:
    stream.write('<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">\n')
    stream.write('<qresource>\n%s</qresource>\n' % ''.join(files))
```

Comment: Amazing man, I cannot find the solution to my problem anywhere but here.
Great Work and Thank you so much for helping me out again LOL. @ekhumoro

Comment: And just out of curiosity is it possible to restore `app.ui` file from `app.py` file also? As I am not able to find anything related to this anywhere also @ekhumoro

Comment: @Aadit. It's difficult to restore the full original. A partial solution is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27135298/984421).