# How to make signals appear in QtDesigner?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qt-signals

The PyQt5 [docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html) says

> "New signals defined in this way will be automatically added to the
>   class’s QMetaObject. This means that they will appear in Qt Designer"

How do I make *anything* appear in QtDesigner if it only knows how to open *.ui files, but not python files?

In my workflow I create ui-file with QtDesigner, then convert it to python using `pyuic5`.
It is thus a one-way conversion (I then subclass it in another file to avoid my code being overwritten).

How do I make QtDesigner "see" my python code?

Comment: [This page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Using_Python_Custom_Widgets_in_Qt_Designer) explains how to insert custom widgets in Qt Designer

Comment: @Heike so you think this is only for custom widgets? The page I quoted says nothing about custom widgets. I was hoping for some kind of "pyunuic" which would convert the generated python file back to .ui file suitable for working with qtdesigner.

Comment: I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822786/converting-py-to-ui-file) question and don't feel that I need such a tool, but this docs quote seems to imply it exists.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you. How do I mark this as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt Designer recognizes 2 types of elements:

- The .ui that are the product,
- And the plugins that are the ingredients.

So if you want a widget to be seen in Qt Designer you must create a plugin, if you download [the source code](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt5/5.12.2/PyQt5_gpl-5.12.2.zip) in the folder examples/designer/plugins there is an example.

On the other hand there is no converter from .py to .ui since the transformation is not possible in all cases.